# How to run gravity ui in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, gravity

I've done everything according to instructions, but styles are not uploading. What could be a problem of it?
[image]

This is the output. It is the button, but it is the text[image]

It just doesn't load the styles. Perhaps I need to change something in the config files. I read the documentation and don’t quite understand what’s connected with that. I don't want to use tailwind, but everything is about tailwind. I want to use gravity ui in my site. Please give advice to anyone familiar with this problem!!!

Comment: can you be a bit more specific about the issue?

Comment: Please post the code as a text, and not an image.

Comment: Could you compare your code to https://github.com/gravity-ui/gravity-ui-nextjs-example and see what the differences are if any? Are you using nextjs app router or pages router? If you're using the app router, could you post your root layout.tsx code?